# Toggle an SVGs <use href> Attribute with JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a runnable code snippet below and here as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ecyxnt?file=index.html

What I would like to know is how I can elegantly accomplish with es6, toggling the `<use href="">` attribute somehow so that the svg switches between the regular and filled version.

I want one svg element that starts out unfilled and on each click it toggle between it's normal state and being filled. I am confused how to do this, if I actually need two svgs in a parent svg in order to use `<use>` or what the best way to implement this would be.

```css
.wishlist-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0 0 0 / 25%);
}

.icon {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Svg &lt;use&gt; href toggle</h1>

<button class="wishlist-btn">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- how can I toggle #wishlist-add/#wishlist with JavaScript? -->
    <use href="#wishlist-add"/>
  </svg>
</button>

<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" id="wishlist-add" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M2.813 10.88l7.204 7.2 7.875-7.873a4.993 4.993 0 000-7.05 4.884 4.884 0 00-6.977 0l-.897.902-.46-.465-.476-.479A4.89 4.89 0 005.594 1.65a4.893 4.893 0 00-3.49 1.465 4.998 4.998 0 00-.001 7.05l.706.706.004.008z"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-width="1.3"
      fill="none"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
    ></path>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" id="wishlist" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M20 6.681c0 1.44-.55 2.88-1.646 3.984L10.017 19l-7.753-7.75-.004-.009-.617-.617a5.649 5.649 0 010-7.966A5.543 5.543 0 015.593 1c1.428 0 2.855.552 3.95 1.658l.476.479.435-.438a5.533 5.533 0 017.9 0A5.64 5.64 0 0120 6.681z"
      fill="currentColor"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
    ></path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: In a case as simple as this, I would simply apply `fill: currentColor` to the first version dynamically via CSS ... `#wishlist-add path { fill: currentColor; }`

Comment: I have a bit more complicated use case but I have here a more simple concept, can you please illustrate what you mean with a small example or explain how I could update the href if I had to. I looked on mdn and I don't quite get the way to structure this with <use>.

Comment: Start by providing an example that actually _has_ a `<use href>` anywhere then.

Comment: alright, updated the OP to better show what I mean. I don't work with svgs and javascript too much so sorry if I am missing something simple here, when the button element is clicked it should just toggle between the below listed svgs.

Comment: Now you duplicated the `wishlist-add` id, your first SVG would practically try to `use` itself now :-) Assume that first SVG's id was replaced with `foobar`, then all you need is `document.querySelector('#foobar use').href = 'wishlist';`

Comment: Got it, thanks for that I was wondering why that wasn't working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why change the DOM using JavaScript when you can use CSS. Here are two examples (with the same technique). In the first the SVG is embedded on the "button". It is more simple, but I guess that you have more buttons on the same page. In that case the second example makes use of `<use>`, so all the buttons can make use of the same SVG. In both examples there is a hidden checkbox. This can be useful if you need to collect information about what items was clicked.

```css
.wishlist-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0 0 0 / 25%);
}

.wishlist-btn input {
  display: none;
}

.icon {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: none;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 1.3px;
}

.wishlist-btn input:checked~.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Svg &lt;use&gt; href toggle</h1>

<label class="wishlist-btn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wishlist" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M2.813 10.88l7.204 7.2 7.875-7.873a4.993 4.993 0 000-7.05 4.884 4.884 0 00-6.977 0l-.897.902-.46-.465-.476-.479A4.89 4.89 0 005.594 1.65a4.893 4.893 0 00-3.49 1.465 4.998 4.998 0 00-.001 7.05l.706.706.004.008z"
      fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

```css
.wishlist-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0 0 0 / 25%);
}

.wishlist-btn input {
  display: none;
}

.icon {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: none;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 1.3px;
}

.wishlist-btn input:checked~.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Svg &lt;use&gt; href toggle</h1>


<label class="wishlist-btn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wishlist" value="1" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#icon" />
  </svg>
</label>

<label class="wishlist-btn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wishlist" value="2" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#icon" />
  </svg>
</label>

<svg width="0" height="0" style="display: none;" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon">
    <path
      d="M2.813 10.88l7.204 7.2 7.875-7.873a4.993 4.993 0 000-7.05 4.884 4.884 0 00-6.977 0l-.897.902-.46-.465-.476-.479A4.89 4.89 0 005.594 1.65a4.893 4.893 0 00-3.49 1.465 4.998 4.998 0 00-.001 7.05l.706.706.004.008z"
      fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this using a css variable. I was trying to emulate something I seen on a site and since I don't work with svgs too much I wanted to know how I could make use of the <use> element.

Answer (score 1):

Use setAttribute on the use element to change its href attribute...

```js
function run(event) {
  let use = event.target.querySelector("use");
  use.setAttribute("href", use.getAttribute("href") === "#wishlist-add" ? "#wishlist" : "#wishlist-add");
}
```

```css
.wishlist-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0 0 0 / 25%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Svg &lt;use&gt; href toggle</h1>

<button class="wishlist-btn" onclick="run(event)">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" pointer-events="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- how can I toggle #wishlist-add/#wishlist with JavaScript? -->
    <use href="#wishlist-add"/>
  </svg>
</button>

<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="wishlist-add" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M2.813 10.88l7.204 7.2 7.875-7.873a4.993 4.993 0 000-7.05 4.884 4.884 0 00-6.977 0l-.897.902-.46-.465-.476-.479A4.89 4.89 0 005.594 1.65a4.893 4.893 0 00-3.49 1.465 4.998 4.998 0 00-.001 7.05l.706.706.004.008z"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-width="1.3"
      fill="none"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
    ></path>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="wishlist" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M20 6.681c0 1.44-.55 2.88-1.646 3.984L10.017 19l-7.753-7.75-.004-.009-.617-.617a5.649 5.649 0 010-7.966A5.543 5.543 0 015.593 1c1.428 0 2.855.552 3.95 1.658l.476.479.435-.438a5.533 5.533 0 017.9 0A5.64 5.64 0 0120 6.681z"
      fill="currentColor"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
    ></path>
  </svg>
```